# How do I autocomplete multiple fields using autocomplete-ui, codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Can fields be autocompleted by #id after the main query autocomplete is executed?

this is the code that I have in my controller:

```
function ajax(){
    if($buscar = $this->input->get('term')){
        //i don't know if the rest after 'name as value' is correct
        $this->db->select('name as value, dir, tel_1, tel_2, tel_3, email');
        $this->db->like('name', $buscar); 
        $query=$this->db->get('client');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $result[]= $row;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

and in my view

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#c5').autocomplete({
        source:'<?php echo site_url('sin/ajax'); ?>',
        //autocomplete other fields by #id?
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});


<td colspan="2"><input size="50" type="text" name="c5" id="c5" class="text" />
              <?= form_error('c5');?></td>
```

Of course I also have other fields that I want to get filled with data that came back when I did the autocomplete.

for example c6 can be tel_1 and c7 tel_2. I want to be able to autocomplete those when I chose the clients name at c5.

```
<td colspan="2"><input size="50" type="text" name="c6" id="c6" class="text" />
              <?= form_error('c6');?></td>
```